# How can I quickly rotate the pixels that make up BitmapData without using BitmapData.draw()?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, rendering, rotation

I've been using [`BitmapData.copyPixels()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) to draw graphics onto a canvas (`Bitmap`).

I need to rotate the resulting graphics without the use of [`draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) because it's vastly slower.

How can I rotate the target graphic? I'm assuming that there might be a formula or library that I can use which will first reorganize the pixels that make up a graphic based on an origin (point) and radians.

I'm pretty certain that I'm not capable of creating such logic, so if there are any known libraries that do this, that would be awesome.

I'd like to achieve something similar to XNA's [`SpriteBatch.Draw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433992.aspx) method, which accepts `rotation` as its 5th argument.

Comment: So . . . are you trying to rotate the BitmapData before you copy the pixels over to the new object, or after?  Or do you care which?

Comment: @iND Whichever is faster, but I have a feeling they would be the same, so either.

Comment: The reason copyPixels is so quick is that it doesn't need to apply any matrix multiplication and therefore doesn't have to infer the values of various pixels as a result of the transformation. copyPixels is a direct copy. The draw() method is the quickest available method for the operation you require. If you're struggling from a slow-down from the draw() method then pre-draw the BitmapData at various given rotations and then choose the closest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copyPixels` basically just copies memory blocks from one `BitmapData` object to another. Transforming the pixels (eg. scaling, rotating, shearing etc.) is *way* more CPU intensive. That's just how things are and there's no magic method to change this. Even if you would find another library that does these things, I doubt it will be any faster than the native implementation as it would have to be implemented in pure ActionScript and cannot be optimized as the native commands are.

If you're blitting your scene (eg. copy sprites to a larger `BitmapData` canvas) and you have to perform a lot of rotations with lots of sprites, then the best way would be to render a discrete amount of render steps to a `BitmapData` and then use `copyPixels` to copy the rotation that is closest to your desired rotation. That way you would use the slow `draw` only once at initialization and then use the fast `copyPixels` from there on.

There's another way for drawing rotated bitmaps, by using the new 3D API, you could simply render textured quads which you can rotate, scale and move to any extent without performance drops. This would be the closest to XNAs `draw` implementation, but it would require you to dump the blitting (draw to a `Bitmap`) entirely.

Overall I would go with the simplest way and just use `BitmapData.draw`. Create a test-case that draws your estimated maximum of concurrent sprites and profile it to see if the performance-impact is so large that it's worth implementing any of the mentioned workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a matrix. There are many examples online, I like this one, it is short and to the point.  http://www.psyked.co.uk/actionscript/rotating-bitmapdata.htm

Comment: I've found a few similar to this but they all use `draw()` which is significantly slower than `copyPixels()`. Is there a way to shuffle the pixels in an instance of `BitmapData` to appear rotated and then use `copyPixels()` still?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas, but speed is untested:

- If the rotations are fixed (e.g., every 30 degrees), create a sprite sheet with the different rotations, and use `copyPixels()`.
- Make the bitmapdata into a bitmap, and rotate the bitmap in front of the other graphics.  Use an object pool to avoid instantiation costs, if there are going  to be frequent removals/additions.  Use cacheAsBitmapMatrix to make rotations a bit faster, though there is more memory usage.
- Look into making a Shader that does the rotation.
- Don't rotate the bitmapdata . . . rotate the world around it.
- Make the animation really, really slow, so no one notices.  This is actually good advice if you can get away with it . . . reduce the framerate until the blitting affects are unnoticeable.